# php strange behavior while changing value

Tags: php

Having this snippet for buffering events.

```
$temp = array();

while ($row = $source)
{
  $temp[] = $row;

   // `add_day` means how many of next days add to buffer

   $d = new DateTime($row->date);

   for ($i = 0; $i < $row->add_day; $i++)
   {
      $d->modify('+1 day');          

      $row->date = $d->format('Y-m-d');

      $temp[] = $row;

      // print_r($row) --> It's OK. `date` has proper value.
   }
}
```

While tracking single event, everything seems to be fine. But in the result - `$temp` array, all rows from forcycle have the same `date` value. (the last one.)

E.G.

```
$data = { date: '2015-07-01', add_day: 2 }
```

Result:

```
$temp[0] = { date: '2015-07-03'} 
$temp[1] = { date: '2015-07-03'}
$temp[2] = { date: '2015-07-03'}
```

Where I am doing a mistake??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep overwriting the value for that date in your object. Since that array has [*references* to the same object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) they all return the same value.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $row->add_day; $i++)
{
    $d->modify('+1 day');          
    // Here you keep updating your object to have the new date
    $row->date = $d->format('Y-m-d');
    $temp[] = $row;
}
```

[Cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) those objects is one way to work around this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $row->add_day; $i++)
{
    $d->modify('+1 day');    
    $tempObj = clone $row;      
    $tempObj->date = $d->format('Y-m-d');
    $temp[] = $tempObj;
}
```